# Progress bars not hitting their values

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, progress-bar

I made few progress bars and tried to iterate through them adding different stop values, but they stop way too early. I tried to fix it, but it seems to be beyond my (rather poor) skills. What's the issue here?

```js
let el = document.getElementsByClassName("skill-bar");

const max = [95, 70, 80, 60, 99, 95];
let width = 0;
let id = setInterval(frame, 50);
function frame() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= el.length; i++) {
    if (width >= max[i]) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        width++;
        el[i].setAttribute('value', width);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <section id="service" class="skills">
        <h2 class="h2">My skills</h2>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">HTML/CSS</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">JavaScript</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">PHP</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Python</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Ruby</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Java</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to mark your finished progress bars with a flag.
- Use `setTimeout` to validate the finished progress bars and get a better control of your `for-loop`.  This is because it can call a new `setInterval`'s iteration before the `for-loop` ends.
- Store the current width into the attribute `value` of each progress bar.

```js
let max = [95, 70, 80, 60, 99, 95];
function frame() {
  let el = document.getElementsByClassName("skill-bar");
  let loop = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    var width = parseInt(el[i].getAttribute('value'));
    if (width == max[i]) {
    } else {
      el[i].setAttribute('value', width + 1);
      loop = true;
    }
  }

  if (!loop) return;
  setTimeout(frame, 1);
}

frame();
```

```html
<section id="service" class="skills">
  <h2 class="h2">My skills</h2>
  <div class="skill">
    <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">HTML/CSS</h3>
    <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">JavaScript</h3>
    <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">PHP</h3>
    <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Python</h3>
    <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Ruby</h3>
    <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Java</h3>
    <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- You're stopping your interval as soon as any of the bars reach their max, instead of only stopping when all have reached their max.
- You're treating the return value of `getElementsByClassName` as if it were an array, when it's an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

```js
let el = document.getElementsByClassName("skill-bar");
const max = [95, 70, 80, 60, 99, 95];

let id = setInterval(frame, 50);
var done = true;
function frame() {
  done = true;
  var bar;
  for (var idx = 0; bar = el.item(idx); idx++) {
    var value = parseInt(bar.getAttribute("value"));
    if (value <= max[idx]) {
        bar.setAttribute('value', value + 1);
        done = false;
    }
  }
  if (done) {
    clearInterval(id);
  }
}
```

```html
  <section id="service" class="skills">
        <h2 class="h2">My skills</h2>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">HTML/CSS</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">JavaScript</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">PHP</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Python</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Ruby</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
          <h3 class="h3 is-upcase">Java</h3>
          <progress class="skill-bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
      </section>
```